# Нужна ли запятая перед оборотом с КОГДА? Сомневаюсь

Tags: запятые

`Я(,) когда домой пришла, уже-таки высохла.`

Comment: А почему дефис?

Comment: Потому таки, что *уже* – это наречие.

Comment: "Уже" — это не то слово, к которому можно отнести "таки". В этом случае оно должно произноситься едино — "ужетаки", а это как-то не по-русски звучит. Его следует отнести к глаголу.

Comment: Правило есть – пишем через дефис. Это не первый раз, как я *уже-таки* пишу. *Ужетаки* – чушь (так же как и ваши попраления меня и – только без обид – моей «нерусской» грамматики). Посмотрите, что у меня насчёт этого в моём профиле неписано-с.

Comment: Произносится так, не пишется, не чушь! "Уже-таки" не звучит по-русски (это в связи с тем, что "уже" имеет особенности частицы). А то, что не звучит по-русски, нельзя считать грамотным. Этот сайт ориентирован не на тех, кто спрашивает, а на тех, кто потом найдёт это и будет пользоваться материалом. Поэтому никакие ошибки здесь не игнорируют. Кстати, у вас их гораздо меньше стало. Значит, растёте. Чем умнее вы становитесь, тем больше будете уходить от неправильного.

Comment: Ошибок орфографических и пунктуационных?

Comment: Нет, стилистических. Мне тоже не нравится это слово, но ничего другого не придумали. Это не только ошибки в стиле (таких очень мало), это неправильное использование слова, плеоназмы, тавтология, неправильный порядок слов, несочетаемость слов и многое другое. Лучше бы и этим интересовались.

Comment: Нет-с – и только нет.

Comment: Прочитайте про виды ошибок: https://www.ismart.org/library/rechevye-oshibki-chto-eto-takoe-i-kak-s-nimi-borotsya Вы только двумя видами занимаетесь. А смысл? Если быть грамотным, то полностью.

Comment: @shampar  Нежелательная правка названия!  Тема становится неузнаваемой и незаметной (в Сети, да и на форуме тоже).  Я ее с трудом нашла.  Просмотров уже много.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны оба варианта. Давайте разберëмся, когда какой.

***Я когда домой пришла, уже-таки высохла.***

В данном случае местоимение **Я** входит в придаточное предложение и можно переставить слова: ***Когда я домой пришла, уже-таки высохла***.
Если предложение в этом смысле, запятую можно не ставить.

***Я, когда домой пришла, уже-таки высохла.***

Здесь автор подразумевает невхождение местоимения в придаточную часть — можно: ***Я уже-таки высохла, когда домой пришла*** — или: ***Когда домой пришла, я уже-таки высохла***.
Если Вы это имели в виду, то запятую можно поставить

Comment: Хорошо. *Иметь в виду* – три слова.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр, я знаю, я хотел написать слитно, но, видимо, не заметил, что не поставил пробел. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: *Если предложение в этом смысле* — нет смысловой разницы.

Comment: @Максим (дополнение к моему комменту).  Я хотел написать: _Я хотел написать __раздельно___. Но почему-то вместо _раздельно_ написал _слитно_.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы все-таки написала так:

*Я, **когда домОй пришла**, уже-таки вЫсохла.*

Произношение фактически **без паузы,** но запятая **грамматическая.**  Здесь ударением обозначено противопоставление **по времени** (когда – уже-таки).

Противопоставлено придаточное **времени** (когда?) и **временное** наречие уже-таки.

В результате получилось противопоставление **двух** фонетических фраз (местоимение **не отделено** от придаточного в устной речи, и это особенность данной структуры предложения).

Я, когда дОмой пришла, // уже-таки вЫсохла.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1. С первого взгляда кажется, что такое невозможно **никогда**. Но вот, оказывается, случается-таки)

Но как? Это **инверсия** подчинительного союза ***КОГДА*** в обычном (грамматически корректном) предложении: *Я **когда** домой пришла, уже-таки высохла.* Сравнить: ***Когда** я домой пришла, уже-таки высохла.*

**Но зачем** здесь инверсия, разве содержание непонятно? Так говорят, но такое высказывание выглядит **как просторечие.**

2. И все таки такой вариант может **найти оправдание**, если инверсия необходима для **логического подчеркивания** при сравнении двух ситуаций (***я — он***).  Тогда два этих местоимения должны находиться в **ударной** позиции, а инверсия как раз и делается для этого:

***Я** когда домой пришла, уже высохла, а **Он** пришел мокрым. Вот и ругайте его))*

Но даже в этом случае можно обойтись **без инверсии**, если и без подсказки правильно расставить ударения:

*Когда **Я** домой пришла, то уже высохла, а **Он** пришел — мокрым.*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148715/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.