# Об инверсии подчинительного союза в придаточном предложении

Tags: запятые, грамматика, спп

1. Рассмотрим предложение из [недавнего вопроса:](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475194/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81-%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%94%D0%90-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C/475196#475196): ***Я когда домой пришла, уже-таки высохла***.

Итак, здесь **инверсия подчинительного союза**, которая в грамматике, как мне думается, нигде не обозначена. Другими словами, это нарушение грамматической нормы.

Но так говорят...  И что же с этим делать? **Правило-то где?**

2. В [справочнике Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)  есть примеры с инверсией главной и придаточной части:

**Пункт 3.** Если главная часть сложноподчиненного предложения находится внутри придаточной (в разговорном стиле речи), то запятая обычно ставится только после главной части (а перед ней не ставится); ср.:  Хозяйством нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался… (Г.) — Нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался хозяйством; Но слова эти мне неудобно, чтобы ты сказала… (Герц.) — Но мне неудобно, чтобы ты сказала эти слова.

3. В нашем случае можно видеть нечто похожее: *Я **когда домой пришла**, уже-таки высохла.*

Главное предложение: *Я уже-таки высохла.* Придаточное предложение: *Когда домой пришла.*

И теперь "вклиниваем" придаточное предложение в главное предложение сразу после подлежащего "я ", и при этом запятую после "я" не ставим.

4. Такая **"трансформация"** характерна для разговорного стиля.

**И сочиняем правило:** Если придаточное предложение  находится внутри главного, то запятая (в разговорном стиле речи) может ставиться только после придаточного (а перед придаточным не ставится). Можно пользоваться новым правилом))

И вопрос: **Вам понравилось такое правило?**  Можно его применять? Или, может быть, есть другое правило?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148735/discussion-on-question-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.